# List all registered variables inside a Laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5. I would like to know which are all variables passed to a view inside the view itself.

Since all variables are in the view scope I thought I could use the generic PHP function: `get_defined_vars();` http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

Something like this:

```
  // resources/view/home.blade.php
  <html>
  <body>
       <?php print_r(get_defined_vars()); ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

But I would like to know if there is a better way (something like `View::getData()`)

**Note:** get_defined_vars() deosn't work becausee it returns hundreds of useless variables (Laravel components)

This is a snippet (partial) using `print_r(get_defined_vars())` (i think it goes in infinite recursion loop):

```
      Array
(
    [__path] => C:\net\laravel\storage\framework\views/8e030a77b0bdbacc2c4182fc04420d1d
    [__data] => Array
        (
            [__env] => Illuminate\View\Factory Object
                (
                    [engines:protected] => Illuminate\View\Engines\EngineResolver Object
                        (
                            [resolvers:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [php] => Closure Object
                                        (
                                            [this] => Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider Object
                                                (
                                                    [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object
                                                        (
                                                            [basePath:protected] => C:\net\laravel
                                                            [hasBeenBootstrapped:protected] => 1
                                                            [booted:protected] => 1
                                                            [bootingCallbacks:protected] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Closure Object
                                                                        (
                                                                            [static] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [instance] => Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider Object
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [defer:protected] => 1
                                                                                            [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                                                        )

                                                                                )

                                                                            [this] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                                        )

                                                                    [1] => Closure Object
                                                                        (
                                                                            [static] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [instance] => Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider Object
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [defer:protected] => 1
                                                                                            [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                                                        )

                                                                                )

                                                                            [this] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                            [bootedCallbacks:protected] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                            [terminatingCallbacks:protected] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                            [serviceProviders:protected] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider Object
                                                                        (
                                                                            [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                                            [defer:protected] => 
                                                                        )
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Use the `dd` helper:

```
{{ dd(get_defined_vars()) }}
```

Read more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-dd

Update (thx, @JoeCoder): you can further cutdown on the "useless" variables by doing:

```
{{ dd(get_defined_vars()['__data']) }}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, that function returns hundreds of useless variables. I cannot post image (not enough reputation) otherwise i could show

Comment: @llnk If you use `dd` as suggested, those "useless" variables are collapsed and only end up showing a handful (of top level variables). Much easier way to see the data (as opposed to `print_r`.

Comment: @llnk just tested it, there's no "hundreds of useless variables": http://i.imgur.com/B6ciHRS.png

Comment: You can further cutdown on the "useless" variables by doing `dd(get_defined_vars()['__data'])`

Comment: Oh got it! I thought `dd()` was an alias of `print_r`. Sorry I cannot upvote this answer because i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @llnk you asked for L5 solution, ``dd`` is one of many great Laravel's helpers.

Comment: I get `FatalErrorException in AbstractDumper.php line 173:                  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!` even with dereferencing `__data` on laravel 5.1 :(

Comment: Use `@php(dump(get_defined_vars()['__data']))` if you want to see the rest of the page still.

Answer (score 13):

Kind of the same, but a bit tidier :

```
{{ dd($__data) }}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Laravel Helper function `dd`

Use `dd` in blade view:

`{{ dd($__data) }}`  OR  `<?php dd($__data); ?>`

Above both methods works in blade view.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Laravel 5.1 which now allows to extend Blade with custom directives you might find this useful. You need to register directives in AppServiceProvider like in this [example](https://gist.github.com/cheelahim/e51d45f9c837254c8fe9) or create you own provider.

```
     /**
     * Blade directive to dump template variables. Accepts single parameter
     * but also could be invoked without parameters to dump all defined variables.
     * It does not stop script execution.
     * @example @d
     * @example @d(auth()->user())
     */
    Blade::directive('d', function ($data) {
        return sprintf("<?php (new Illuminate\Support\Debug\Dumper)->dump(%s); ?>",
            null !== $data ? $data : "get_defined_vars()['__data']"
        );
    });

    /**
     * Blade directive to dump template variables. Accepts single parameter
     * but also could be invoked without parameters to dump all defined variables.
     * It works similar to dd() function and does stop script execution.
     * @example @dd
     * @example @dd(auth()->user())
     */
    Blade::directive('dd', function ($data) {
        return sprintf("<?php (new Illuminate\Support\Debug\Dumper)->dump(%s); exit; ?>",
            null !== $data ? $data : "get_defined_vars()['__data']"
        );
    });
```