# Request list of all variables used in blade view template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

We have a series of blade view templates that are out going emails and would like to create a simple way for our in house administration to preview these emails without actually sending them.

I could keep tract of, and provide filler variables but am very curious if there is a way to request a list of variables used in a view?

For example, I have a basic view "greeting.blade.php" that says:

```
Dear {{$customerFirstName}} {{$customerLastName}},
```

I'd like to:

```
$usedVariablesArray = getVariablesFromView("greeting");
```

And have it return:

```
['customerFirstName', 'customerLastName']
```

Is there anything built into laravel that provides this kind of functionality?

[EDIT]
I'd like to do this from outside the view file in question.

```
public function previewEmailTemplate($templateName) {
    $usedVariables = $getArrayOfVariables($template);
    // Would return ['customerFirstName', 'customerLastName']

    foreach($usedVariables as $aUsedVariable) {
        $dummyValues[$aUsedVariable] = $aUsedVariable;
    }

    return view($template, $dummyValues)->render();
}
```

So this function would render the template with the variable names in the place of the variables.

Does that make my question clearer?

Comment: possible duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146879/list-all-registered-variables-inside-a-laravel-view

Comment: how do u assign those two variables that u are trying to get ?

Comment: go to your controller and see which variables are getting passed through

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all registered variables inside a Laravel view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146879/list-all-registered-variables-inside-a-laravel-view)

Comment: @ad_on_is You may be right and I am going to look into the responses to that question now.  Leo_Kelmendi : By passing the template name, and an array of variables to Mail::send(). Chris: Doh!  But then I'd have to do this for every new email template that is ever added to the system, and store that list somewhere.  Than update it if the email changes.  I prefer to simply write a function that will return said variables.  Much like what is potentially in the response from ad_on_is.

Comment: @ad_on_is the question you posted was in regards to getting that list from within the view.  I need the list before a view is rendered and have updated my question.  Thanks

Comment: So, as far as I understood, you want to render your template like this `Dear customerFirstName customerLastName, ` instead of `Dear {{$customerFirstName}} {{$customerLastName}},` whereas the wording`customerFirstName` should be in variable `$customerFirstName`... somewhere in your controller you MUST have a code where you assign values from the user-model to these variables. Can't you just use the same approach and dummy-populate this variables with what you need in your preview-function?

Comment: Yes I can and currently that is the plan.  Ideally I'd like to setup a situation where I do not need to create a list of and populate dependent variables, and instead write the function you see in my edit, provide it a template name and let it do that work.

Answer (score 2):

I also need such function but not find on the net.

I write a simple function to do it.

May help you

`greeting.blade.php`

```
Dear {{$customerFirstName}} {{$customerLastName}},
```

`functions.php`

```php
function getVariablesFromView($templatePath)
{
    // $templatePath = '/resources/views/mails/greeting.blade.php'
    $contents = file_get_contents($templatePath);

    $re = '/{{[\ ]*\$[a-zA-Z]+[\ ]*}}/m';
    preg_match_all($re, $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    $flatternArray = [];
    array_walk_recursive($matches, function ($a) use (&$flatternArray) {$flatternArray[] = $a;});
    $variables = str_replace(['{{', '}}', '$', ' '], '', $flatternArray);

    return $variables;
    // ['customerFirstName', 'customerLastName']
}
```

p.s.
this function doesn't support advanced blade syntax such like `@extend('xxx')`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the first answer to this question 董承樺, my answer is merely an extension of what you wrote to cover slightly more use cases. Feel free to update your answer with this improved code if you like.

Specifically, this version support php variable names that contain underscore like $very_good_variable etc. It also supports the "unescaped" Laravel Blade syntax, which is {!! $something_something !!} instead of {{ $something_something }}. Regex is not my strong suit, and I am sure there is way to get this to work with more succint code, but it does seem to work effectively.

```
function getVariablesFromView(($templatePath){
                        //this version tests for standard blade variables... of the form {{ $something_something }}
                        $re = '/{{[\ ]*\$[a-zA-Z_]+[\ ]*}}/m';
                        preg_match_all($re, $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
                        $flatternArray = [];
                        array_walk_recursive($matches, function ($a) use (&$flatternArray) {$flatternArray[] = $a;});
                        $regular_variables = str_replace(['{{', '}}', '$', ' '], '', $flatternArray);

                        //this version tests for unescaped blade variables... of the form {!! $something_something !!}
                        $re = '/{!![\ ]*\$[a-zA-Z_]+[\ ]*!!}/m';
                        preg_match_all($re, $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
                        $flatternArray = [];
                        array_walk_recursive($matches, function ($a) use (&$flatternArray) {$flatternArray[] = $a;});
                        $unescaped_variables = str_replace(['{!!', '!!}', '$', ' '], '', $flatternArray);

                        $variables = array_merge($regular_variables,$unescaped_variables);
                        return $variables;

}
```