# Laravel 5.8 - How to dump parameters from controller in the view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm fresh beginner in the PHP Framework Laravel (i'm using version 5.8), and i would like to dump all the variables of a controller from a view. Is that possible to do that ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel internally uses a `$__data` array which contains all available variables (including variables [shared with all views](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views).

In addition it contains an instance of `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` (as `$__data['app']`) and an instance of `Illuminate\View\Factory` (as `$_data['__env']`).

You can filter these out with `\Illuminate\Support\Arr::except($__data, ['app', '__env'])`.

But you should not rely on this since it's an internal variable which might change in a future update without any warning.

Comment: Do you have an idea how Laravel forward data from controller to view or in case of redirect to another page ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but Laravel does not automatically pass data from the controller to the view, you'll have to do that manually.

Answer (score 1):

First you should pass variables from controller to view.Best way is to use `compact` in second argument of return view like this:

```
return view("viewName",compact("variable1","variable2",...));
```

Notice that in compact just use variable name without `$` sign.

After pass variables to view you can use `{{dd($variable1)}}` or `{{echo($variable1)}}` (e.g) in every where you like to see variables.

`dd()` do not allow to debug remaining codes and die program for show variable and it is better for debugging.But `echo()` is for release version.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
{{ dump($variable); }}
```

OR

```
@php dump($variable); @endphp
```

**Update**

List all registered variables inside a Laravel view

```
{{ dump(get_defined_vars()['__data']) }}
```

See [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146879/list-all-registered-variables-inside-a-laravel-view)