# Laravel, array of passed variables to view

Tags: php, laravel, view, routes, associative-array

I'm new with Larabel. I'm checking some stuff before i use it for production

```
Route::get('/{lang}/user/{user}', function ($lang,$user) {
    return view('user',compact("lang","user"));
})->where('lang', '[a-z]{2}');
```

In the view, is there any way to get an array with the variables passed ($lang and $user) in this example... something like the "old" $_GET when you are doing a typical php

I know that you can use {{$user}} and {{$lang}} inside the view to get them, but I would like an associative array with all them, just the array passed to the view function as second parameter.

That associative array would containt 2 elements

["lang"] and ["user"] in my example.

In my case, if the path is **/en/user/John** I would get this associative array

```
["lang" => "en",
 "user" => "John"]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146879/list-all-registered-variables-inside-a-laravel-view

Comment: i saw and tried that one before asking, not what I wanted, you get a lot of stuff, and I dont see my parameters inside that big object

Comment: What you can do is to pass a third parameter, like `$myVars = ['myVars'=>compact("lang","user")];` and then `return view('user',compact("lang","user","myVars"));`

Comment: I want to see if there is an option inside laravel. You dont need the third parameter in that case, just pass all variables inside an associative array and use it with {{}}, but I'm checking if that feature is native.

Comment: about the stack overflow post that you shared, i have tried it searching for the variables inside the structure, and no luck :E

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it after a while

```
dd(request()->route()->parameters);
```

This is exactly what I wanted.